# integrate ssh into windows explorer shell

Tags: windows, ssh, windows-explorer

In much the same way that you can go to start.. Run.. and type `telnet:localhost` and have telnet start & attempt to connect to the host
I want to be able to do `ssh:localhost` or `ssh//:localhost` and have putty start and do the same.

Is that possible?  how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Like so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: thank you! i'd been searching on msdn for ages trying to find this.  not enough key words obviously!